# Multiple setInterval in a HTML5 Canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to achieve multiple animations in a game that I am creating using Canvas (it is a simple ping-pong game). This is my first game and I am new to canvas but have created a few experiments before so I have a good knowledge about how canvas work.

First, take a look at the game [here](http://cssdeck.com/t/egkk1kra/7).
The problem is, when the ball hits the paddle, I want a burst of n particles at the point of contact but that doesn't came right. Even if I set the particles number to 1, they just keep coming from the point of contact and then hides automatically after some time.

Also, I want to have the burst on every collision but it occurs on first collision only. I am pasting the code here:

```
//Initialize canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    W = window.innerWidth, 
    H = window.innerHeight,
    particles = [],
    ball = {},
    paddles = [2],
    mouse = {},
    points = 0,
    fps = 60,
    particlesCount = 50,
    flag = 0,
    particlePos = {}; 

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackPosition, true);

//Set it's height and width to full screen
canvas.width = W;
canvas.height = H;

//Function to paint canvas
function paintCanvas() {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
}

//Create two paddles
function createPaddle(pos) {
    //Height and width
    this.h = 10;
    this.w = 100;

    this.x = W/2 - this.w/2;
    this.y = (pos == "top") ? 0 : H - this.h;

}

//Push two paddles into the paddles array
paddles.push(new createPaddle("bottom"));
paddles.push(new createPaddle("top"));

//Setting up the parameters of ball
ball = {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    r: 5,
    c: "white",
    vx: 4,
    vy: 8,
    draw: function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
};

//Function for creating particles
function createParticles(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;

    this.radius = 0.8;

    this.vx = -1.5 + Math.random()*3;
    this.vy = -1.5 + Math.random()*3;
}

//Draw everything on canvas
function draw() {
    paintCanvas();
    for(var i = 0; i < paddles.length; i++) {
        p = paddles[i];

        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.w, p.h);
    }

    ball.draw();
    update();
}

//Mouse Position track
function trackPosition(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
}

//function to increase speed after every 5 points
function increaseSpd() {
    if(points % 4 == 0) {
        ball.vx += (ball.vx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        ball.vy += (ball.vy < 0) ? -2 : 2;
    }
}

//function to update positions
function update() {

    //Move the paddles on mouse move
    if(mouse.x && mouse.y) {
        for(var i = 1; i < paddles.length; i++) {
            p = paddles[i];
            p.x = mouse.x - p.w/2;
        }       
    }

    //Move the ball
    ball.x += ball.vx;
    ball.y += ball.vy;

    //Collision with paddles
    p1 = paddles[1];
    p2 = paddles[2];

    if(ball.y >= p1.y - p1.h) {
        if(ball.x >= p1.x && ball.x <= (p1.x - 2) + (p1.w + 2)){ 
            ball.vy = -ball.vy;
            points++;
            increaseSpd();

            particlePos.x = ball.x,
            particlePos.y = ball.y;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    else if(ball.y <= p2.y + 2*p2.h) {
        if(ball.x >= p2.x && ball.x <= (p2.x - 2) + (p2.w + 2)){ 
            ball.vy = -ball.vy;
            points++;
            increaseSpd();

            particlePos.x = ball.x,
            particlePos.y = ball.y;
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    //Collide with walls
    if(ball.x >= W || ball.x <= 0)
        ball.vx = -ball.vx;

    if(ball.y > H || ball.y < 0) {
        clearInterval(int);
    }

    if(flag == 1) {
        setInterval(emitParticles(particlePos.x, particlePos.y), 1000/fps);
    }

}

function emitParticles(x, y) {

    for(var k = 0; k < particlesCount; k++) {
        particles.push(new createParticles(x, y));
    }

    counter = particles.length;

    for(var j = 0; j < particles.length; j++) {
        par = particles[j];

        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.arc(par.x, par.y, par.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();  

        par.x += par.vx; 
        par.y += par.vy;

        par.radius -= 0.02; 

        if(par.radius < 0) {
            counter--;
            if(counter < 0) particles = [];
        }

    } 
}

var int = setInterval(draw, 1000/fps);
```

Now, my function for emitting particles is on line 156, and I have called this function on line 151. The problem here can be because of I am not resetting the `flag` variable but I tried doing that and got more weird results. You can check that out [here](http://cssdeck.com/t/egkk1kra/8).

By resetting the `flag` variable, the problem of infinite particles gets resolved but now they only animate and appear when the ball collides with the paddles. So, I am now out of any solution.

Comment: this question has been solved here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/multiple-setinterval-in-a-html5-canvas-game

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems here.

your main short term problem is your use of setinterval is incorrect, its first parameter is a function.

```js
setInterval(emitParticles(particlePos.x, particlePos.y), 1000/fps);
```

should be

```js
setInterval(function() {
    emitParticles(particlePos.x, particlePos.y);
}, 1000/fps);
```

Second to this, once you start an interval it runs forever - you don't want every collision event to leave a background timer running like this.

Have an array of particles to be updated, and update this list once per frame. When you make new particles, push additional ones into it.